# How to ensure only one of many possible consumers reads from a Stream?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am building a distributed application that has many nodes receiving messages from clients through HTTP requests. All those messages have a "topic" attached to them, which makes all messages with the same topic to be logically bundled together.

The nodes then have to process those messages, but all messages of a topic must be processed by the same node. Besides that, if this node eventually becomes offline, I need some other node to take over as the processor of that topic.

Considering the requirements above, I thought about using Redis Stream for that, but I am not entirely sure it fits my use case.

I am not an expert on Redis Streams, but I thought about 2 possible solutions:

**Approach 1**

Since many nodes may get a message at the same time of the same topic, I thought about using a distributed lock so one of the nodes acquires the lock and then registers itself as a consumer to that specific topic.

Then, when other nodes get a message of that topic, they can simply write it to the stream which is then read by the consumer.

To recover from the consumer going offline: every few seconds, the other nodes may try to check if there is a consumer registered for that topic. If not, then one of the nodes may try to acquire the distributed lock and register itself as a consumer.

**Approach 2**

I wonder if Redis allows many consumers to register to a topic, but only allow one of them to read the messages. Some type of configuration, maybe on consumer groups, that will limit the number of consumers that will get streams for the group, but still allow others to take over if the main consumer goes offline. This way I don't have to build workarounds for recovering from a specific node shutting down.

My question is: are my approaches valid? Is there any other better possibility out there?

Comment: Approach 1 looks good to me, except that you need to do topic management, so that your system can consume messages from new topic added.